# is there any solution to error in nodejs " Cast to Number failed for value "undefined" at path "

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have a little problem to understand that how to solve this error.i am just a beginner to nodejs and mongodb/mongoose.I am creating a component in reactjs to update any particular documents using its user_id which i am passing a params in routes.
there is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const user = require('../schema');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
  const userid = {
    userid: (req.params.id || '')
  }
  console.log('getting to be updated data');
  user.db1.findOne(userid, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err
    res.send(data)
    console.log(data)
  });
});
module.exports = router


//here is the user model:

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
userid:{type:String},
fullname:{type:String},
phone:{type:Number},
email:{type:String},        
})
const skillSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userid:{type:Number},
    skills:{type:String},
})
const users = mongoose.model('users',userSchema);
const skills = mongoose.model('skills',skillSchema);

module.exports ={
    db1 : users,
    db2 : skills
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the model  user model?

Comment: i have added the user model.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't specified in the find.one () function by which parameter it will search. Try it by typing your own column name instead of id.

```
user.db1.findOne({ id: userid } ,function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err
        res.send(data)
        console.log(data)
});
```

Or you can change your function and use findById().

```
user.db1.findById(userid, ,function(err, data){
            if (err) throw err
            res.send(data)
            console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: findById() method is only work when you want match with _id property which is auto generated and created by mongodb